# Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdowns buttons. If i click outside/OR on it  ,it closes BUT if i click the another dropdown button it wont close and the other one pops down. I want to close it when i click the other button or anything outside it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Acasa</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()" style="cursor:pointer">Infinatri firme</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="infintare_societate_limitata.php"> Societate cu raspundere limitata (S.R.L.) </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction1()" style="cursor:pointer">Modificari firma</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
        <a href="modificari_actualizare_date.php">Actualizare date de identificare</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the css as well. I dont see the dropdowns in your code snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u1cbsaje/    using the solution below. Not sure if its right

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yg593q3o/#&togetherjs=qjgcs7rltG

Answer (score 2):

You can tell any click hide the dropdown, and any click that makes it to the parent of the dropdown to stop bubbling.

```
/* Anything that gets to the document
 /* Anything that gets to the document
   will hide the dropdown */
$(document).click(function(){
  $("#dropdown").hide();
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
$("#dropdown").click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I told you i am begginer. I would be very thanks full if you would show me the full implementation

Comment: Added. Nothing seems to happens

Comment: did you add a link to the JS in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the close of the `myDropdown1` on click event of `myDropdown` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this.

```js
function myFunction(event, dropDownName) {
  //Pass in your dropdownName which is the dropdown  
  var dropDownHandler = document.getElementById(dropDownName);

  dropDownHandler.classList.toggle("show");
  // Get the trigger element of the dropdown
  var menuHandler = event.currentTarget;

  if (dropDownHandler.classList.contains("show")) {
    //Attach only when the dropdown is active,
    //to ensure onclick isn't called always
    document.addEventListener("click", function(docEvent) {
      documentHandler(docEvent, menuHandler)
    });
  } else {
    dropDownHandler.classList.toggle("show");
    // If is closed, remove the handler
    document.removeEventListener("click", documentHandler);
  }

  function documentHandler(event, menuHandler) {
    if (menuHandler.contains(event.target)) {
      dropDownHandler.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      dropDownHandler.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Acasa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(event, 'myDropdown')" style="cursor:pointer">Infinatri firme</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="infintare_societate_limitata.php"> Societate cu raspundere limitata (S.R.L.) </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(event, 'myDropdown1')" style="cursor:pointer">Modificari firma</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
        <a href="modificari_actualizare_date.php">Actualizare date de identificare</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long while, but I feel tempted to answer this in case someone finds himself in that situation.
So you have two buttons, therefore a loop is needed to close the dropdown contents each.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}


  // This is what I added. you have 2 dropdowns, therefore a loop will
  // close the dropdown content if the user clicks outside of it

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Acasa</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()" style="cursor:pointer">Infinatri firme</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="infintare_societate_limitata.php"> Societate cu raspundere limitata (S.R.L.) </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction1()" style="cursor:pointer">Modificari firma</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
        <a href="modificari_actualizare_date.php">Actualizare date de identificare</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```